# why jquery isVisible does not work along with scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is as shown below;

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var scroll_start = 0;
    var startchange = $('.q-intro-text');
    var offset = startchange.offset();
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scroll_start > offset.top) {
            $('#q-nav').css('background-color', 'black');
        } else {
            $('#q-nav').css('background-color', 'transparent');
        }
    });



    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");
        $('a').each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top + 2
        }, 500, 'swing', function() {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
            var scroll_start = 0;
            var startchange = $('.q-intro-text');
            var offset = startchange.offset();
            $(document).scroll(function() {
                scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
                if (scroll_start > offset.top) {
                    $('#q-nav').css('background-color', 'black');
                } else {
                    $('#q-nav').css('background-color', 'transparent');
                }
            });
        });
    });
});

function onScroll(event) {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#q-nav a').each(function() {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#q-nav ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
            // $('#q-nav').css('background-color', 'red');

        } else {
            currLink.removeClass("active");
            // $('#q-nav').css('background-color', 'transperant');

        }
    });
}
```

```css
#q-nav {
     width: 100%;
     height: 8rem;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     padding-top: 3rem;
 }
 
 #q-nav ul {
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
     -webkit-box-direction: normal;
     -ms-flex-direction: row;
     flex-direction: row;
     -webkit-box-pack: end;
     -ms-flex-pack: end;
     justify-content: flex-end;
 }
 
 #q-nav .q-nav-about {
     position: relative;
     color: #ffffff;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding: 0rem 2rem 0 2rem;
 }
 
 #q-nav ul li {
     list-style: none;
 }
 
 #q-nav .q-nav-work {
     position: relative;
     color: #ffffff;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding: 0rem 2rem 0 2rem;
 }
 
 #q-nav .q-nav-contact {
     position: relative;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #ffffff;
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 0rem 8rem 0 2rem;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../test/css/index.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="q-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active q-nav-about " id="is-visible" href="#about-us">ABOUT US</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="q-nav-work" href="#work">WORK</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="q-nav-contact" href="#contact-us">CONTACT US</a>
            </li>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</body>
```

For this , I am following [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/). Now everything works fine. But what I want to do is when user scroll down, the color of nav menu should change,which is happening. and when the user scrolls back to the first page automatically the nav menu should become transparent. For that I am using isVisible function, but somehow it is not able to detect when **active** is visble? so is there any other way through which I can know that?

Comment: you want on click or on scroll?

Comment: No, what I want is by-default navbar would be transparent, but as soon as I scroll-down it should become black and when scroll-back to top , it should become transparent again.

Comment: Arre you sure the issue is that it doesn't select the element and not just that it can't apply your styling since you have misspelled "transparent"?

Comment: ok  . i try to solve it .

Comment: Mrugesh Thaker  check here https://jsfiddle.net/ayatullahrahmani/9y001n1r/

Comment: @AyatullahRahmani it is working. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> here is working example  -

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".menu").addClass("changeBg");
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    
    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");
        
        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');
      
        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        var id = $("#menu-center a:first").attr('href');
        if(target == id){
         $(".menu").addClass("changeBg");
         }
         else{
         $(".menu").removeClass("changeBg");
         }
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
        }, 500, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });
});

function onScroll(event){
if ($('#menu-center a:first').hasClass('active')) {
     $(".menu").addClass("changeBg");
}
else{
$(".menu").removeClass("changeBg");
}
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#menu-center a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        var id = $("#menu-center a:first").attr('href');
      
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#menu-center ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color:#000;
    position: fixed;
    background-color:#000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.light-menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    position: fixed;
    background-color:rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
#menu-center {
    width: 980px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#menu-center ul {
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
#menu-center ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
    display: inline;
}
.active {
    font-family:'Droid Sans', serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
a {
    font-family:'Droid Sans', serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
#home {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(images/home-bg2.png);
}
#portfolio {
    background-image: url(images/portfolio-bg.png);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#about {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#contact {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.changeBg{background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);}
.changeBg a{color:#000}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m1 menu">
    <div id="menu-center">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="home"></div>
<div id="portfolio"></div>
<div id="about"></div>
<div id="contact"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = $('.active');
```

You need to use a `.` before`active` since it's a class name.

Comment: i did this, but still it is not detecting the visible event