# Smooth Scrolling to Anchors not working with hash and forward slash in the href

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling, anchor-scroll

I have a one page site with anchor (# linking) linking to different parts of the document. The active gets highlighted when scroll down/clicked.

The codes are working but the problem is, when I have the href like `<a href="/#anchor">Anchor</a>`, it does not seem to work with my codes. If I have the same without the forward slash, it works like `<a href="#anchor">Anchor</a>`

Any help will be appreciated.

Here are two fiddles

- https://jsfiddle.net/ayanize/vu5bxh85/3/ - does not work
- https://jsfiddle.net/ayanize/sc92tL8L/23/ - works

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav">
<!--with the forward slash before the #, it DOES NOT work--->
<li><a href="/#one">One Menu</a></li>
<li><a href="/#two">Two Menu</a></li>
<li><a href="/#three">Three Menu</a></li>
<li><a href="/#four">Four Menu</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="all-sections">
<div id="one" class="section">
<h2>ONE</h2>
</div>
<div id="two" class="section">
<h2>TWO</h2>
</div>
<div id="three" class="section">
<h2>THREE</h2>
</div>
<div id="four" class="section">
<h2>FOUR</h2>
</div>
<div id="five" class="section">
<h2>FIVE</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click( function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          var anchor = 0;
         if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
              anchor=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
         }else{
          anchor = $(this.hash).offset().top - 24 ;
           }
         $('html,body').stop().animate({scrollTop:anchor}, 1000,'swing');
     });
 $('.nav li a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('a').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.section').each(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top - 50) {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('.nav li a').removeClass('highlight');
            $('.nav li a[href=#'+ id +']').addClass('highlight');
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
ul.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
ul.nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background: #39a25a;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.all-sections {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 46px;
}
.section{
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  background: red;
}
.highlight{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: hey check here answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084245/why-jquery-isvisible-does-not-work-along-with-scroll-function/44084790#44084790

Comment: Thanks but it has the same pattern <a href="#anchor"> but what I am looking for a fix for this <a href="/#anchor">. Moreover, the menu items are not even highlighted on scroll